# why is curl prints HTML code of the page?

Tags: curl, buildbot

I am trying to trigger a buildbot build using following command ,the output of this is a plain HTML output of the URL being used, how do I debug this problem ?how do figure out the right curl command? why is it outputting the HTML code?

```
curl https://username:password@tech.company.com/builders/companyABCW%20rootTest%20Yukon -d train="name1" -d build="17A267" -d usernameala" -d forcescheduler="ForceTasksAUTO" -d projectSHA="2b888c42835af4d1138e1ab5ba965e6944bc4652"
```

Comment: Try wrapping the url in quotes...

Comment: @duhaime - that didn't help

Comment: Ah what the heck am I saying, curl is doing what it should. If you want to pipe the html out into something, use a vertical pipe and xargs or something: `curl https://twitter.com | grep swift-boot`

Comment: @duhaime - No,the output shouldn't be HTML,it should trigger a build which isn't happening

Comment: can you link to the buildbot documentation that says you should use curl in this way?

Comment: http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.14/index.html is the buildbot documentation for the version am using..I found this command over google

Comment: I don't see curl anywhere in the docs at least -- I would read and follow the documentation if I were in your position...